# How to set timezone in jquery countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set GMT+5:30 as my timezone in jquery countdown. 
Start Time for countdown is 'Thu May 20 16:00:00 IST 2010'
End Time is 'Thu May 20 17:00:00 IST 2010' as value.

+330 is my timezone given in minutes. 
But my countdown starts from 00:35:00. 
I would have expected the countdown to start from 01:00:00
Not sure why this is discrepancy is there.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var endTime = '#{myBean.getCountDownDate()}';
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
                until: endTime, format: 'HMS',
                timezone: +330,
                compact: true, description: '#{myBean.getCountDownDate()}'});
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: appreciate any hints to resolve this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the `until` parameter the countdown plugin counts down until that time.

This will run for one hour using the correct offset.

```
$('#countdown').countdown({
    until: $.countdown.UTCDate(+330, 2010, 6-1, 20, 17),
    format: 'HMS',
    compact: true
});
```

Since 2010:06:20:17 has already passed it will display 00:00:00.

I would bet the reason you got 00:35:00 in your countdown is that you were looking at it around 2010:06:20:16:25.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you change your End Time format to 'Thu, 20 May 2010 17:00:00 IST'?

-edit-

It looks like you're not supposed to pass the date value to until as a String.  You can pass in a Date to specify the exact date/time, but a string is only supposed to be used as a time offset, which is why you always get the same amount of time remaining when you refresh.

I couldn't get Date to convert the string with the 'IST' time zone, so I ended up using 'GMT+05:30'.  I also put the timezone offset in terms of hours instead of minutes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var endTime = "Tue, 29 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT+0530";
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: new Date(endTime), format: 'HMS',
        timezone: +5.5,
        compact: true, description: endTime.toString()});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried with the format you have provided. My countdown starts from 00:34:40. My endTime is 'Sat, 26 Jun 2010 09:00:00 IST'.

Answer (score 0):

to set timer with eastern timezone

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        var timeZone = "America/New_York";
        var TimerEndDate = "Nov 25 2022";
        var endHour = 23;
        var endMinute = 59;
        var endSeconds = 59;
    
        //for starting time for timer 
        //bydefault set to america current time
        var nowDate = new Date();
        var nowTimeZone = convertTZ(nowDate, timeZone); 
        var now = new Date(nowTimeZone.getFullYear(),nowTimeZone.getMonth(),nowTimeZone.getDate());
        now.setHours(nowTimeZone.getHours(), nowTimeZone.getMinutes(), nowTimeZone.getSeconds());
    
        var endDate = new Date(TimerEndDate+" "+endHour+":"+endMinute+":"+endSeconds);
        var endDateTime = convertTZ(endDate, timeZone);
        var future = new Date(endDateTime.getFullYear(),endDateTime.getMonth(),endDateTime.getDate());
        future.setHours(endHour, endMinute, endSeconds);
    
        var difference = Math.floor((future - now) / 1000);
    
        var seconds = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
        difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    
        var minutes = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
        difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    
        var hours = fixIntegers(difference % 24);
        difference = Math.floor(difference / 24);
    
        var days = difference;
        $("#seconds").text(seconds + "s");
        $("#minutes").text(minutes + "m");
        $("#hours").text(hours + "h");
        $("#days").text(days + "d");
    }, 1000);
    function convertTZ(date, tzString) {
        return new Date((typeof date === "string" ? new Date(date) : date).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: tzString}));   
    }
    function fixIntegers(integer)
    {
        if (integer < 0)
            integer = 0;
        if (integer < 10)
            return "0" + integer;
        return "" + integer;
    }
    </script>
    <span id="days"></span>
    <span id="hours"></span>
    <span id="minutes"></span>
    <span id="seconds"></span>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).