# jQuery Countdown using a single timezone and 24 hour reset

Tags: jquery, countdown, jquery-countdown

I've been beating my head against this for hours now and could use an extra set of eyes. :-)

I'm trying to set up a jQuery countdown that resets every 24 hours at 3pm EST and the timer should display in EST regardless of timezone.

I'm using Keith Wood's jQuery Countdown plugin on a WordPress site. http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html

I found this thread on the jQuery forums that helped me get to where I'm currently at. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/countdown-plugin-how-to-restart-countdown-timer-every-24-hours

I was also able to take a look at the guys site from that thread where the exact functionality I need is working correctly. http://bedeals.com

So I'm thinking I must just be missing something obvious. Anyone mind taking a look at the code I've written for this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function serverTime() { 
        var time = null; 
        $.ajax({url: 'http://72.52.139.171/~eyedictive/wp-content/themes/eyedictive/servertime.php', 
            async: false, dataType: 'text',
            success: function(text) { 
                time = new Date(); 
                //alert(time);
            }, 
            error: function(http, message, exc) { 
                time = new Date(); 
                //alert("test");
        }}); 
        return time;

    } 

    function getCountDown() {
        var until = getNowEDT();
        until.setHours(15,0,0,0); // Next 3pm
        return until;
    }

    function getNowEDT() {
        var now = new Date(); 
        now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + now.getTimezoneOffset() - 4 * 60); // EDT is UTC-4
        return now;
    }   

    $('#home-timer').countdown({until: getCountDown(), compact: true, serverSync: serverTime, format: 'HMS', timezone: -4,
        onExpiry: function() {
            alert('We have lift off!'); 
            $(this).countdown('change', {until: getCountDown()});
    }});    

}});
```

And this is servertime.php contents:

```
<?php
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n";
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3121381/2765490